VBA in Outlook to Update an Excel File
I have a macro that is auto sorting emails into different queues, and part of the macro is to record the information into an excel file. I attempted to add debugging steps but I'm getting an "Error 1004: Application-Defined or Object-defined error" after I get the debugging message "Sheet 'Requests' accessed successfully"
 ' Update the Excel file on SharePoint with the request details
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True ' Make Excel visible for debugging
    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("FILE PATH HERE") ' Update with the actual SharePoint URL to your Excel file
    MsgBox "Workbook opened successfully."

    ' List all sheet names for debugging
    Dim sheet As Object
    Dim sheetList As String
    sheetList = "Sheets in workbook:" & vbCrLf
    For Each sheet In xlWorkbook.Sheets
        sheetList = sheetList & sheet.Name & vbCrLf
    Next sheet
    MsgBox sheetList

    ' Access the specified sheet
    sheetName = "Requests" ' Updated sheet name
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlSheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error accessing sheet '" & sheetName & "': " & Err.Description
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    MsgBox "Sheet '" & sheetName & "' accessed successfully."

    ' Debugging: Check the last used row
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox "Last used row in column A: " & lastRow

    ' Update the sheet with the request details
    On Error Resume Next
    xlSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = Now ' Timestamp
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error updating timestamp: " & Err.Description
        Exit Sub
    End If
    xlSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = additionalEmails ' Number of additional emails requested
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error updating additional emails: " & Err.Description
        Exit Sub
    End If
    xlSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = movedCount ' Number of replies assigned
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error updating moved count: " & Err.Description
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    xlWorkbook.Save
    xlWorkbook.Close
    xlApp.Quit

it would open the excel file and add a tame stamp at the bottom of column A and the number of new emails into column b and replies into column c.

Are you using late binding?  If Yes then your outlook code doesn't know the value of Excel VBA constants such as xlUp  unless you've declared them elsewhere in your code.   If you comment out On Error GoTo ErrorHandler you can see which exact line has the problem.
